# How to deal timeout error?

Tags: timeout, endpoint, wso2

I have a service. If the endpoint can not response in 30 seconds. I will discard message. I set this in endpoint, but no use, someone tell me this is a bug. So I want to use a error sequence to deal this. But still failed. Anybody can tell me how to do this?

```
If the endpoint can not response in 30 seconds, then execute EndpointError sequence.
Best regards.

<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="EndpointTest" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence onError="EndpointError">
         <log level="full" />
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence onError="EndpointError">
         <log level="full" />
         <send />
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://172.21.11.158:48280/portalAgent/services/receiveMsg" format="pox">
            <timeout>
               <duration>3000</duration>
               <responseAction>discard</responseAction>
            </timeout>
         </address>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Answer (score 1):

The duration Param is stablished in milliseconds and you are configuring 3000 so it always gonnna to suspend. If you want to control the error for supension you have to contron in the target section like this.

```xml
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="EndpointTest" transports="https,http" statistics="disable" trace="disable" startOnLoad="true">
<target faultSequence="EndpointError">
    <inSequence onError="EndpointError">
        <log level="full" />
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence onError="EndpointError">
       <log level="full" />
        <send />
    </outSequence>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="http://172.21.11.158:48280/portalAgent/services/receiveMsg" format="pox">
            <timeout>
                <duration>30000</duration>
                <responseAction>discard</responseAction>
            </timeout>
        </address>
    </endpoint>
</target>
```